# Justification for using nonlinear autoregressive models when modelling covariance stationary processes

Tags: time-series, stationarity

A lot of research has been done that focuses on developing nonlinear autoregressive models (NAR) in both econometrics (eg. Threshold Autoregression, Exponential Autoregression) and machine learning (eg. Neural Network or Tree based NAR models) and I was wondering what the justification was for the use of these models in the case of stationary time series given the Wold decomposition theorem.

More precisely, the Wold decomposition theorem tells us that any covariance stationary time series $Y_t$ can be written as the sum of a deterministic time series and a MA($\infty$).
The MA($\infty$) can then be approximated infinitely well (under some conditions on the coefficients of the MA($\infty$)) by a finite order ARMA(p,q) model.

Is the use of the nonlinear time series models (NAR) therefore only useful for cases where the conditions on the coefficients of the MA($\infty$) do not verify an invertibility condition?

Thank you for your help!